# Atheros ar5b125 Wireless Driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, compatibility

I have an Atheros ar5b125, can't find any drivers for it, all I've seen are drivers for Windows7, none for any Linux distro. What should I do to get it working under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to install the Backports:

Backports were not enabled by default for all releases before (but not including) Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot). On these releases, backports must be manually enabled before you can install packages from Backports.

Enabling Backports on Ubuntu Desktop

Open the Software Sources control applet. On Ubuntu 10.10 and earlier, click System -> Administration -> Software Sources. On Ubuntu 11.04 and later, search for Software Sources in the Dash.

You will be asked to enter your password. Once you have done that, switch to the Updates tab.

Make sure Unsupported updates is checked.

Open a terminal and `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`